# Module import failures in Apollo Server

Tags: typescript, apollo-server, typescript-types

I'm getting an endless flood of error messages after importing Apollo Server into a Typescript-based Node.js application. (See a screenshot down below)

It seems Apollo can't find anything in the `graphql` dependency. It must be a Typescript setting, but what is it?

Here's my `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/customTypings",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "files": [
    "./node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts",
    // "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.json",
    "src/**/*.css",
    "src/**/*.map",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.svg",
    "src/public/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: I built a new Node project, and it seems the errors occur if I specify `baseURL` or `paths` in `tsconfig.json`. It doesn't matter what the value is.

Answer (score 2):

No answer all day, what gives, SO? This place used to be much more active! Anyway, here's the solution.

1. In `tsconfig.json` add these settings:

```
"lib": ["ES2022"],
"target": "ES2022",
"module": "CommonJS",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"baseUrl": ".",
"types": ["node"],
```

This goes against Apollo's own documentation, where they recommend using `ESnext` but don't listen to them. Also, `baseURL` must be `"."` because any other setting will disrupt Apollo. Don't ask me why, I didn't research it.

2. Install `tsc-alias`, a handy utility that turns Typescript paths into absolute paths in your build. Your `start` script may then look like this:

```
"start": "tsc && tsc-alias --f && node dist/
```

You need the `--f` flag to generate complete file names, with extension.

3. Do not set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`! This is, again, the opposite of what Apollo recommends.